# Shiny-server Laravel authentication

Tags: r, laravel, shiny, shiny-server

There are 2 applications on my server. One is a laravel application with login etc, and the other one is a shiny server with some shiny apps.

The apps are created through my laravel system and in the database is stored who has access to a shiny app.

Laravel is running on: `<domain>:80 & <domain>:443`

Shiny server is running on: `<domain>:3838`

What I want to achieve is that users have to be logged in in the laravel application and have access to the shiny app to be able to run the shiny app in the browser.

Is there a way to achieve this? And if yes, what is a good way to go?